# Error while calling PLSQL procedure from spring boot simple JDBCcall

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, plsql, spring-jdbc

I'm new to Spring boot development and JAVA, asking for your help as i tried all the suggestions which i got from stackoverflow but none worked for me.

I'm trying to call Oracle PLSQL procedure from Spring Boot Application using Simple JDBCcall.

But i'm getting error as mentioned below:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'WELCOME_MSG1' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70) ~[oracle-jdbc-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133) ~[oracle-jdbc-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206) ~[oracle-jdbc-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455) ~[oracle-jdbc-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413) ~[oracle-jdbc-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034) ~[oracle-jdbc-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:191) ~[oracle-jdbc-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:950) ~[oracle-jdbc-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1222) ~[oracle-jdbc-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387) ~[oracle-jdbc-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3488) ~[oracle-jdbc-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:3857) ~[oracle-jdbc-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1374) ~[oracle-jdbc-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1138) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1135) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1083) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1135) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:405) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:365) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:198) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.mud.listcontractsretriever.testproc.TestMain.testClass(TestMain.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mud.listcontractsretriever.controller.ListContractsRetrieverRestController.postMethodIsInlandPricing1(ListContractsRetrieverRestController.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
```

PLSQL Procedure code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE welcome_msg1 (p_name IN VARCHAR2,message OUT VARCHAR2) 
IS
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line ('Welcome '|| p_name);
message:= p_name;
END;
/
```

Spring boot Class:

```
package com.mud.listcontractsretriever.testproc;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class TestMain {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource datasource;

    private SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    public DataSource getDatasource() {
        return datasource;
    }

    public void setDatasource(DataSource datasource) {
        this.datasource = datasource;
        this.jdbcTemplate =new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
        this.simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(this.jdbcTemplate);
    }

    public SimpleJdbcCall getSimpleJdbcCall() {
        return simpleJdbcCall;
    }

    public void testClass(String name){
        jdbcTemplate =new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
        simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate);

        simpleJdbcCall.withProcedureName("WELCOME_MSG1");
        simpleJdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("p_name", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
        simpleJdbcCall.withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();
        SqlParameterSource in= new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("p_name", name);
        Map<String, Object> out = simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);   
    }
}
```

Please help.

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to call MySQL stored procedure in spring boot using hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281009/how-to-call-mysql-stored-procedure-in-spring-boot-using-hibernate)

Answer (score 2):

Try giving permission on your db to the user, something like:

```
grant execute on (packageName or tableName) to user;
```

Comment: Hi, i tried providing grant as well but it didn't work. Also i'm using same user from JAVA as well in which i have created the Procedure. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Still think some permission issue as it looks like the call can't see the function, one more thing, try to prefix the function with the schema name when you create i.e. Schema_Name.WELCOME_MSG1

Comment: Thank You Very Much. This worked !!! After creating procedure appended with schema name the issue got resolved. Thanks

Comment: Glad it did :). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, that you've created your procedure as `welcome_msg1` but access it using `WELCOME_MSG1`. Try changing one of them.

Comment: Hi Halko, I tried changing to same case, but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't to do with SpringBoot it's the query you're trying to execute. As per the stack trace it's throwing a `ORA-06550` error, which means your SQL is not correct and it tells you `WELCOME_MSG1 must be declared`, you need to specify what `WELCOME_MSG1` will be. See this example in the section where there is a similar problem: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora06550.php